# Why is my flag still disputed?

Tags: support, flags

While reviewing my flagging history, I noticed that I had one disputed flag.  AFAIK, that means that someone without privileges to actually *dismiss* it said they thought I was wrong.

I flagged [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25227/how-do-i-change-my-name-via-the-command-line-of-the-minecraft-exe) as a duplicate of the question it was closed as a dupe of.

So clearly, the mod(s) agreed with my flag.  Why is it still disputed?  Shouldn't the decision of a mod overwrite a dispute between non-mods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Disputed flags are flags that one or more 10k users have marked to be invalid. You do not lose or gain flag weight to those, regardless of their validity or invalidity, and so don't those who disputed it.

When a flag is dismissed invalid by a moderator, the flag is marked "Invalid." You do lose 10 flag weight to those.

Comment: So even if a mod later agrees, once disputed, always disputed?

Comment: @John Yes, that's accurate.

Comment: But if a mod disagrees and marks it as invalid, a disputed flag does not cost anyone flag weight, does it?

Comment: @Arda Correct: disputed flags are [weight neutral](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/how-should-we-handle-flag-weight-for-invalid-flags/95029#95029).