# What is the difference between a declined and disputed flag?

Tags: support, flags

I found [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/why-is-my-flag-still-disputed) here on meta, but that just says how a flag becomes disputed:

> Disputed flags are flags that one or more 10k users have marked to be invalid.

What is difference then between a declined flag and a disputed flag?  Isn't a declined flag a flag that is also marked invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flags generally push the question or answer into one of the review queues. A disputed flag is when the review completes, and the community disagreed with your flag. For example, if you flag something as not an answer, it pushes the answer into the low quality review queue. If it gets enough Looks OK votes to complete the review, your flag would be disputed.

Declined flags are manually done by moderators, when reviewing from the flag queue itself.

Comment: So basically, a disputed flag is a flag where multiple members of the community deemed the post in question to be valid, and a declined flag is when a **moderator only** finds it invalid and marks it as so?

Comment: That's my understanding of how it works; only moderators can decline flags, and only through the flag queue. If they vote through the regular review queues, their vote completes the review, but only generates a dispute, not a decline.